# function not working and nothing is happening

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to insert a data or record inside firebase realtime database.

I am using firebase 9.14.0. Upon clicking the button there are no errors or prompts. What's the problem?

Here is my code:

```
var crops = document.getElementById('cropName').value;
var cropDetails = document.getElementById('cropInformation').value;

function insertData(){
 set(ref(database, "Crops/"),{
    CropName: crops,
    CropDetails: cropDetails
 })
 .then(()=>{
    alert ("successfully inserted");
 })
 .catch((error)=>{
    alert ("unsucessful, error");
 });
}

addCrop.addEventListener('click', insertData);
```

I checked if I am connected with firebase, I am. And I am expecting to get my data inserted to their realtime database, but nothing is happening.

Comment: Where does the addCrop variable come from?

Comment: It comes from my submit button. Upon clicking it, nothing is happening. crops and cropDetails are text areas.

Comment: Try adding a console.log('foo') inside your insertData function, just before calling the "set" function: if nothing is printed then the error likely has to do with wrong button id or js script not being imported correctly

Comment: I tried it, It shows for a split second then it'll be gone after. What's the cause of this?

Comment: If the message gets removed from the console after being printed, it seems to me like the page is being refreshed, maybe there's an <a></a> element messing around?

Comment: Okay I found the solution. I changed a tag from "Form" to "div" now it works.